# hadoop in a shared file system

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I want to run hadoop to process big files, but server machines are clustered and share a file system. So, even if I log in different machines, I have same file directories and files. 
In this case, I don't know how to get started. I guess splitted files don't have to be transferred within HDFS to other nodes, but I'm not sure how to configure or start. 
Is there any reference or tutorial for this??

Thanks

Comment: I didn't quite get the question.

Comment: I'm skeptical that Hadoop will provide much benefit if they all share a single file share.  I see a huge I/O bottleneck.

Comment: Tariq. There are tens of linux machines, and I can log in any of machines using ssh or vnc server. When I log in machine 1 or machine 2,3, ..,  all directories like /usr, /etc, /proc, etc. are same. I'm not an expert in this clustered environment, but, anyway, in this environment, I want to know how to run hadoop. all directories are shared among the machines, seemingly, file mirroring or transfer among the nodes doesn't have to be necessary, but i wonder if it is possible or hadoop supports this ..